# Getting dependencies paths of the root project in Mix

Tags: c, compilation, elixir, elixir-mix, erlang-nif

As my project consists of some mix projects using nifs, I'm trying to make a custom compiler, so that *.c files could be compiled along with these mix projects. Let's say I have a project A, which has a dependency of B, that has some native code depending on C. The problem arises, when C is also a dependency of A - then from Bs perspective location of Cs code is unknown, because it depends on the way of linking C to A (especially when it's linked by path), which makes it impossible to link *.c files of C to B. That is why I would like to have access from a dependency (in this case B) to a roots (A) other dependencies paths. To solve this, I considered putting native sources to the `priv` folder, that can be accessed by `Application.app_dir/2`, but I don't wish to include the sources in release. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Would not [umbrella app](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html) solve this issue?

Comment: I think it's not the case - I have mix projects and use some of them in other projects (aggregation), afaik umbrella matches more for one project and its submodules (composition). I am also not sure, how would it help in my case